# Given the X, Y, width and, height variables How do I find the start and end values of a shape in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, figma-api

So I was able to grab the width, hight, X, and y value of a frame in Figma. However, Google App Script is asking for start and the end of the the index of the shape in Google App script. how do I manipulate the values of X and Y to get the start and end of the the index I'm not even sure what the start and the end of the box is and how to find it.

How do I work with these the width and the height variables to find the start and end value of a shape in Google App Script

I am using Figma API and Google App Script 
My end goal is to make Ann exporter from Figma to Google Slides

## JSON File

```
absoluteBoundingBox: {
                  x: -460,
                  y: -333,
                  width: 586,
                  height: 586
                },
```

## Google App Script

```
   var frameJSON.x = {};
   var frameJSON.y = {};
   var frameJSON.width = {};
   var frameJSON.height = {};



var subRange = textRange.getRange();
    Logger.log(
      "Sub-range Start: " +
        subRange.getStartIndex() +
        "; Sub-range End: " +
        subRange.getEndIndex() +
        "; Sub-range Content: " +
        subRange.asString()
    );
```

Comment: What do you want o achieve? Why are you using [textRange.getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getrangestartoffset,-endoffset) to deal with shapes? This is meant for text.

Comment: @ZektorH I need to create a shape and then put the text in the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert a [shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape) with SlidesApp you can [`getText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getText()) to retrieve the [`TextRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range) object in it.

You can then manipulate this object to insert the text you want into your shape.

Here is some sample code:

```
function insertShapeWithText() {
  //sample shape data  
  var x = 300;
  var y = 250;
  var width = 100;
  var height = 3000;
  var text = "Bla bla bla";

  var pre = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = pre.getSlides()[0];
  var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.DIAMOND, x, y, width, height);
  shape.getText().setText(text);
}
```

Comment: yep @zektorH I figured this question out after I asked it thanks